# Configuring CNAME record for use with Google Sites for co.cc domains

Tags: dns, cname, google-sites

I'm using Google Sites **without** Google Apps.

I registered a free domain at co.cc and wish to use my *Google Sites* site by Mapping *Google Sites* site to my own URL

***At the co.cc configuration panel, I added a new CNAME record :***

Host :  www.tedxeasternmetropolitanbypass.co.cc
TTL :   1D
Type :  CNAME
Value : ghs.google.com

And at the Google Sites panel https://sites.google.com/site/tedxembypass/system/app/pages/admin/address

I added: www.tedxeasternmetropolitanbypass.co.cc

Nevertheless, http://www.tedxeasternmetropolitanbypass.co.cc/ doesn't seem to work.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working for me. Did you give it *enough* time after you added it? Don't forget that DNS propagations take ~24hrs to complete (around the world).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Google sites

- open your site
- click on manage site
- click on web address
- add your co.cc address in it

and wait for 24 hours.